# Possible to track hover over transparent div without the div affecting any elements it covers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, mouseenter

I want to place a 100px x 100px transparent div on a page

I want to track whether the mouse hovers over it

I don't want this transparent div to affect any elements on the page it might be "covering", i.e preventing any hover/click events that might be attached to those elements (I have no way of knowing what events might be attached to those elements, if there are any).

Is this possible using javascript/jQuery ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to track the mouse over a certain page region, it would probably be better to register the handler on that div itself. If you have more clarity to provide, it might help me answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of browser support you require, you might consider the CSS property `pointer-events` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), note support only in IE 11):

```
.transparent-div {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In browsers that support/implement CSS `pointer-events` you can set the property to `none`, to allow the pointer's behaviour to, essentially, 'pass-through' the element. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
```

With the CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NNYL6/) (tested *only* in Chrome 31/Win XP).

The click events are fired on the `li` elements below the absolutely-positioned image.

With the same HTML and CSS, the following jQuery also allows for the `hover()` method to be used:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NNYL6/1/)

References:

- [`pointer-events` compatibility (caniuse.com)](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).
- [`pointer-events` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).
- [`pointer-events` (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/Submission/pointer-events/).

Comment: If you turn off pointer events, how do you track the hover? ISTM OP's entire approach is wrong and an element in the background should be listening for mousemove events, not a transparent element on top.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the elements under the div to not trigger any of their events of hover but you want to track the mouse being over the transparent div? How do you want to track it? Sounds like you might just be able to do it with CSS maybe (z-index). There maybe be events in the jquery documentation too. CSS below maybe

```
#myDiv
{
    Z-index:1000;
}

#myDiv:hover
{
    Background-color:red;
}

#underDiv
{
    Z-index:1;
}
```